# Access two-dimensional array via pointer to first element

Tags: c

I got strucure

```
typedef struct 
{char *cells;}
 Map;
```

and cells suppose to be pointer to array of rows(in rows are integers on every position).
  I don't know how to access for example to number on 3. position in 2. row.
  I have stared with some array[3][3], but I don't know how to connect them with this struct.
  I tried

```
Map nextmap;
nextmap.cells[0] = array[0][0];
```

But I got only first number, which is clear. How can I get to other positions?
 Thanks in advance.
 EDIT: renaming the structure ..
   .

Comment: Note: You're dereferencing an indeterminate pointer, and thereby invoking **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: using `new` as the name for your structure is pretty iffy...

Comment: Why must you use `char *cells;` (as you indicated in a comment to an answer) instead of a different declaration for `cells`? Is the array to which cells will point an actual two-dimensional array (declared with something like `char array[rows][columns];`) or a pointer to pointers? Is the number of columns in the array fixed at compile time or stored in a variable?

Comment: because it's in a assigment in our school project :/

Comment: @JakubFedor: Please answer the remaining two questions.

Comment: first one, cells point do two-dimensiaon array, second, not fixed

Comment: @TopGunCoder Only in c++. This is plain c, there's no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did `Map nextmap;`, you created an **uninitialized** Map struct. When you did `nextmap.cells[0] = array[0][0];` you dereferenced (i.e. followed) the uninitialized pointer, and stored a value at the random memory it points at.

If you want to initialize the cells structure, you can do something as simple as `nextmap.cells = array[0];` That will cause `nextmap.cells` to **point at** array. Note that it's not copying the contents; just pointing at them. That means that if you change the values through cells, you'll be modifying the values in arrays.

(Also, using 'new' as a variable name is perfectly acceptable in C, but you're likely to confuse any C++ programmers reading your code, since 'new' is an operator in that language.)

<sup>`new` now changed to `nextmap` in question</sup>

*Edited to correct the type mismatch in `nextmap.cells` assignment.*

Comment: `new.cells = array` will cause problems because the type of `new.cells` is not appropriate for a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Ye, I know, but I have to use one dimensional array to point to array of rows.
EDIT: assigment from incompatible pointer type
EDIT2: I have to use this struct

Comment: Either the declaration of `cells` should be changed to match the type of `array` or (less desired) a cast should be inserted into the assignment.

Comment: If you want to point to the row, you can do *new.cells = array[0];*, assuming that array is a char[][]. The type of array[0] would then be a char[], which automatically decays to char*.

Comment: After you've assigned arrays[0] to new.cells, the first item in the row will be new.cells[0]. The second item will be new.cells[1].

Answer (score 1):

Given an array `char array[][NumberOfColumns]` (the first dimension is irrelevant and is omitted here; it would be needed when the array is defined), you can set a pointer to the first element of the array with:

```
nextmap.cells = &array[0][0];
```

Then you can access an element in the array, `array[i][j]`, by calculating its position within the array, with either of these two expressions:

```
*(nextmap.cells + i*NumberOfColumns + j)
nextmap.cells[i*NumberOfColumns + j]
```

Two-dimensional arrays generally ought to be addressed as two-dimensional arrays. Calculating the position manually is poor practice if done without good reason. If this school assignment did not have a good reason for this, then it is a bad assignment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `new` is not a good name for a variable.

<sup>`new` now changed to `nextmap` in question</sup>

Second of all in your case `cells` should be a double pointer, like this

```
char ** cells;
```

Or a pointer to a 2D array, like

```
char (*cells)[N][N];
```

where N is a constant you want to use.

Comment: `char (*cells)[N][N];` is an inappropriate declaration if `cells` is to be assigned with `cells = array;`, where `array` is declared as `char array[N][N];`. If you keep the current declaration, `cells` would have to be assigned with `cells = &array;`, and elements would have to be accessed with three dereferences, as `(*cells)[i][j]`.